# flutter Segmentation fault(11)

Tags: flutter, gitlab-ci

Trying to use gitlab ci to build my app bundle. This my code

```
variables:
  PLAY_STORE_JSON: $PLAY_STORE_JSON
  KEY_PROPERTIES: $KEY_PROPERTIES
  UPLOAD_KEYSTORE: $UPLOAD_KEYSTORE

build:bundle:
  stage: build
  image: cirrusci/flutter:3.3.5
  tags:
    - docker-app-dev
  before_script:
    - cd android
    - echo $KEY_PROPERTIES > key.properties
    - echo $UPLOAD_KEYSTORE > app/upload-keystore.jks
  script:
    - flutter clean
    - flutter build appbundle
  after_script:
    - rm -f ./android/app/upload-keystore.jks ./android/key.properties
```

Every time I receive this error and I couldn't understand the reason

```
../../runtime/bin/eventhandler_linux.cc: 416: error: Failed to start event handler 

thread 1
===== CRASH =====
si_signo=Segmentation fault(11), si_code=1, si_addr=0x10
Aborting re-entrant request for stack trace.
/usr/bin/bash: line 134:    12 Aborted                 (core dumped) flutter clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Bro we spend tone of time to fix it as in google its 0 info about it, solution that help us, just update docker to newest version on your machine where runner is located, not sure that its help to you, but you can try

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).